# How to call a function from root component to another component inside <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a header component which is injected into app.component.html(as i want it to be fixed). All other components are defined in `<router outlet>`. Every component has a function `showData()` that should be called when date(in the header component) changes. How can I achieve this?. Do I have to use ActivatedRout Configurations?

app.component.html

`<app-header></app-header>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: the usual way would be to define a service and inject it into components that need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"></router-outlet>

activeComponent: any;

onRouterOutletActivate(component: any) {
    this.activeComponent = component;
}

dateChangedEvent() {
    this.activeComponent.showData();
}
```